# Angular 13 Firebase wont compile - No exported member with firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

Disclaimer: I have reviewed these posts and they dont seem to answer my question:
[AngularFireModule and AngularFireDatabaseModule not being found in @angular/fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68939014/angularfiremodule-and-angularfiredatabasemodule-not-being-found-in-angular-fire)

[No exported member error with firebase when trying to compile angular 10 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64572609/no-exported-member-error-with-firebase-when-trying-to-compile-angular-10-project)

[ERROR in node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559103/error-in-node-modules-angular-fire-firebase-app-module-d-ts/64612430#64612430)

My current angular dependencies from my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~13.0.0",
        "@angular/common": "~13.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~13.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "~13.0.0",
        "@angular/fire": "^7.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "~13.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "~13.0.0",
        "firebase": "^8.10.0",
        "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
        "tslib": "^2.3.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
    },
```

Imports and declarations:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import {firebase} from '@firebase/app';
import { AngularFireModule} from '@angular/fire/compat'
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/database';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomepageComponent } from './homepage/homepage.component';
import { AddPostComponent } from './components/add-post/add-post.component';
import { PostDetailsComponent } from './components/post-details/post-details.component';
import { PostListComponent } from './components/post-list/post-list.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomepageComponent,
    AddPostComponent,
    PostDetailsComponent,
    PostListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Based on the above posts, this combination of @angular/fire and firebase should work. I have the 7.0.0+ which means I neat the compat portion of the @angular/fire modules, and I have firebase 8.X.X which I believe is the correct level of firebase to work with fire 7.

Still I'm getting a list of the following errors:

```
./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire.js:17:98-111 - Error: export 'isSupported' (imported as 'isSupported$1') was not found in 'firebase/messaging' (module has no exports)

./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire.js:18:104-117 - Error: export 'isSupported' (imported as 'isSupported$2') was not found in 'firebase/remote-config' (module has no exports)

./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire.js:84:29-36 - Error: export 'getApps' (imported as 'getApps') was not found in 'firebase/app' (possible exports: default)
```

Is there anything about firebase I'm not understanding or a version I should downgrade to in order to get this app to compile?

Sorry if the answer is in one of the links posted and I just dont understand it. I am trying to avoid downgrading both modules to lower versions if I can avoid it, but if that's the only answer then that's the only answer. I just want to know if there's anything obvious to someone more practiced than I am that I'm missing.

EDIT: I understand that if I was importing firebase then I would need to import firebase/compat/**, but if you look at the errors, this seems to be how @angular/fire is attempting to import these modules and I dont know how to force it to import the compatibility module.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will solve your issue, but I was facing a similar issue and installing the `rxfire` package fixed my issue for me.

Comment: Well, I must say go through the code and versions on this repo https://github.com/angular/angularfire

Answer (score 1):

This is incompatibility issue, as you are using angular 13, it is compactable with the fire base version 9.x.x, so please upgrade the firebase to version 9.x.x

For NPM

```
npm i firebase@9.6.3
```

or
For Yarn

```
yarn add firebase@9.6.3
```

You can also refer the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade

Thanks & Regards